# Adding teammates using API through Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, sendgrid, teammate

I want to automate a process of adding new teammates to sendgrid. I manually used to add them via CURL which worked. To fully automate this I would need to achieve the same via Powershell. I converted the curl over to invoke-restmethod and it is throwing invalid JSON error. After spending a day it seems to me the body is exactly the same as the CURL request but it still fails. Can anyone help me with this? Below is the code I'm using:

```
$uri = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/teammates"
$emails = "test1@domain.com", "test2@domain.com"
$subusers = "subuser1", "subuser2"
$sendgridApiKey= "full_admin_key"

foreach ($email in $emails){
    foreach ($subuser in $subusers){

        $headers = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer " + $sendgridApiKey; "Content-Type"=          "application/json"; "on-behalf-of" = $subuser}
        $Body = @{
            email= "$email"
            scopes="alerts.create","alerts.read"
            is_admin="false"} | ConvertTo-Json

        echo "Inviting $email to subuser $subuser"
        #echo Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body
    }
}
```

Original curl:

```
declare -a emails= (test@mail.com)
declare -a subusers= (realsubuser1 realsubuser2)
set -a 
sendgridApiKey="RealOneInScript"
set +a
for e in ${emails[@]}
do
    for s in ${subusers[@]}
    do
    
        echo "Inviting $e to subuser $s"
        #invite user, scope is applicable to marketing users
        curl -X "POST" "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/teammates" -H "on-behalf-of:$s"  -H "Authorization: Bearer $sendgridApiKey" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \
        '{
        "email":"'$e'","validations.email.read","validations.email.create","email_testing.read", "2fa_required"],
        "is_admin":false
        }'
    sleep 10 
    done
done
```

Comment: Please post the original `curl` call, and the error message you receive in full

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen iv added the original Curl. FYI in the first script it has no scopes but i can confirm that i had them there at some stage and it changed nothing.

Comment: Original curl body seems to be different then in PowerShell - is there any docu about accepted JSON format?

Comment: I couldnt find much, the only thing i found is sendgrid own examples: https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/teammates/invite-teammate

The body content in both is a little different but thats not whats critical, the "variables" within seem quite similar to me, might just be that iv been staring at it too long...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be **is_admin** value - it should be Boolean type instead of string - try

```
        $Body = @{
            email= "$email"
            scopes="alerts.create","alerts.read"
            is_admin=$false} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: You are right. Thanks a lot, im pretty sure i removed the is_admin trigger at some point but i guess i had another issue at that time.